# How to provide `__snprintf_chk` to a process in Alpine Linux

Tags: linux, postgresql, shared-libraries, postgresql-9.4, alpine-linux

I have compiled a PostgreSQL plugin, [wal2json](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json), but when try to load it in PostgreSQL, it complains:

> ERROR: could not load library "/usr/local/lib/postgresql/wal2json.so": Error relocating /usr/local/lib/postgresql/wal2json.so: __snprintf_chk: symbol not found

I found this documentation for [__snprintf_chk](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/libc---snprintf-chk-1.html).

**Where it is and what should I do to provide it to the plugin?**

My guess is that it's in some core library but not present in the version I have. Maybe I could link it statically?

---

Update: I figured out that this is an issue of Alpine Linux which uses `musl` instead of `glibc`.
I have installed the Alpine packages for `glibc`, as done in https://github.com/jeanblanchard/docker-alpine-glibc/blob/master/Dockerfile . Didn't help, still the same error.

Comment: from the docs it appears to be in glibc.

Comment: I had a similar issue with [node-gdal](https://github.com/naturalatlas/node-gdal) and solved it by [building GDAL linking against shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54875605/506695).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to another base Docker image, Ubuntu.
The result is a bit bigger image, but `__snprintf_chk` is available and works.

Also, PostgreSQL has a Docker image that already has `wal2json` available, which I used in the end for the production.

Comment: Yeah, I know, It's not a real solution, but the only one I had. I think it's still a valid answer, which spares people few hours of trying. Unless someone comes with something better.

Answer (score 2):

alpine uses musl libc instead of glibc, lacking some libs as you can check by `ldd`.

solution:
check and install [glibc](https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc) pkg, or gcompact or libc6-compat

```
apk add gcompat
```

see also:[Docker Alpine executable binary not found even if in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963068/docker-alpine-executable-binary-not-found-even-if-in-path)