# Docker image with Alpine Linux: an executable file is definitely there but cannot be found while trying to execute

Tags: linux, bash, docker, alpine-linux

Here is the output of my terminal, while I am inside the shell of a Docker container with an Alpine image:

```
bash-5.0# ls
makeThumb
bash-5.0# ./makeThumb 
bash: ./makeThumb: No such file or directory
bash-5.0#
```

As you can see, I have an executable file called `makeThumb`, and it is definitely there (see the output of `ls`). However, it is strange that when I'm trying to execute it with `./makeThumb` it says `No such file or directory`.

How to solve this?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:14 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --production
COPY . .

FROM mhart/alpine-node:14
RUN apk update && apk add bash
COPY --from=build /app/ /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm prune --production
EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Output of `ldd makeThumb`:

```
ldd makeThumb 
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f0c421ae000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f0c421ae000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f0c421ae000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f0c421ae000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x7f0c42015000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f0c421ae000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7f0c42001000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f0c421ae000)
Error relocating makeThumb: __strdup: symbol not found
Error relocating makeThumb: __vfprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating makeThumb: __sprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating makeThumb: __snprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating makeThumb: __vsnprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating makeThumb: __strcat_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating makeThumb: __memset_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating makeThumb: __fprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating makeThumb: __memcpy_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating makeThumb: __longjmp_chk: symbol not found
```

Comment: Can you include your image's Dockerfile?  Are you correctly copying the PNG file you attached into the image; `COPY j27cg.png .`?  Where does the `makeThumb` binary come from, and how is this PNG file related to it?

Comment: @DavidMaze Included the Dockerfile. This PNG file `j27cg.png` does not relate to the Docker image in any way. It is just a screenshot

Comment: Could be that the `makeThumb` program is compiled to target another architecture than the one you are using. Can you post the result from `file makeThumb` and `uname -a` ?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ldd makeThumb` ? It could be a missing dependency. EDIT: actually, don't post it, just make sure all the dependencies are met ;)

Comment: That Dockerfile doesn't obviously produce or run a binary named `makeThumb`.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, the Dockerfile does not run it itself. The Nodejs application deployed in this image invokes this executable.

Comment: @ShellCode I have run `ldd`, at the output has something like this: `Error relocating makeThumb: __strdup: symbol not found`

Comment: That sounds like it would be useful to add in full to the question itself. The line(s) before it probably reveal which library is missing.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963068/docker-alpine-executable-binary-not-found-even-if-in-path/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpine makes use of [musl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musl) which is a minimalistic libc. My guess is that your binary is using non-standard functions that do not exist under Alpine.

I see two solutions to that :

- Try to install [glibc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library) in your docker container
- Probably the easiest solution : try to find a Docker image that uses it as default (a minimalistic Debian/Ubuntu Docker should do it)

Comment: The 2nd solution helped, just the image size got a little larger, and that's not a big problem for me. Thanks