# Docker unable to find file in Alpine Linux container

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, file-not-found

I have an application I'm creating a docker image for, the image is created but when I run it the container errors saying it cannot find the executable file.

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM alpine:3.14
WORKDIR /
EXPOSE 3000
COPY ./weather-api /weather-api
CMD ["/weather-api"]
```

I've included a `RUN ls -la` immediately above the `CMD` which shows the file is there whilst building the image is being built, and I've included a shell script with `la -la` as the CMD which has shows that the files is there when the image is being ran.

This is the error I'm getting:

```sh
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory
```

When I try to call the weather-api from a shell script I get the standard file not found error.

I've tried using an absolute and relative path for the command, copying the file to `/usr/local/bin` which I think should put it on the PATH so it would be callable from anywhere, changing `COPY` to `ADD`.

I'm still new to docker so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is "apline" a typo or is it really apline?

Comment: And as alpine is based on musl libc, if your program is compiled to link to glibc or other dynamic libraries, it will also error out with "no such file or directory".

Comment: What is weather-api? How was it created?

Comment: Sorry apline is a typo, its correct in the dockerfile

Comment: weather-api is the application I'm trying to run in docker, its a web api written in rust and cross compiled for armv7 to run on a raspberry pi, the errors I'm getting are when trying to build and run the docker image on a raspberry pi.

Comment: @M.Zhang the program does link to some dynamic libraries so I've tried changing from alpine to ubuntu;xenial and its now working. Thanks

Comment: `file not found` error on Alpine Linux, when the file is actually present, is typical symptom of a dynamic linking error when trying to run binaries that were built on non Alpine distros (e.g. Ubuntu, Debian). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963068/docker-alpine-executable-binary-not-found-even-if-in-path/66974607

Comment: If you can, build the binary using an alpine container (checkout docker multi-stage builds), then you should have no problem running it on alpine as it will be compiled against the alpine SO's rather than the GNU SO's. Even better if you do the build on your rpi too, then you won't need to cross-complie.