# can't run executable in bash docker container

Tags: linux, bash, docker

**Update** - After talking with @CharlesDuffy I tried using `ldd gam` but I got a weird error coming up:

```
bash-5.1# ldd gam
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f38c7ef6000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f38c7ef6000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x7f38c7eb6000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f38c7ef6000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f38c7ef6000)
Error relocating gam: __strcat_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating gam: __snprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating gam: __vfprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating gam: __realpath_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating gam: __memcpy_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating gam: __vsnprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating gam: __strcpy_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating gam: __fread_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating gam: __fprintf_chk: symbol not found
```

currently trying to google the issue now.

**Original post** - I am new to docker, I would like to run an executable from bash inside an alpine docker container. I am getting `command not found`

I googled the issue and found out that Alpine doesn't come with bash. So I installed it according to this stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40944512

However It seems I still can't run an executable, even from bash.

I also performed `chmod 755 gam` to make sure the file was executable. - Still failed

I tried this on a laptop using git bash to make sure the execute works - success - However, I can't get this to work in the container for some reason.

Here is my attempt from the container's CLI:

```
/app # ls
AppCreationScripts        app.py                    indexhtmls                static
Dockerfile                app_config.py             requirements.txt          templates
__pycache__               flask_session             requirements_old.txt      tempninjacode.py
apis                      functions                 routes                    tempninjarefreshtoken.py
/app # cd functions
/app/functions # ls
__pycache__                    main.py                        msexchange.pfx
gam_startup                    microsoft_functions.ps1        msexchangepython.pem
intermedia_pwsh_functions.ps1  microsoft_functions.py
/app/functions # cd gam_startup
/app/functions/gam_startup # ls
gam_1  gam_2    gam_3
/app/functions/gam_startup # cd gam_3
/app/functions/gam_startup/gam_3 # ls
GamCommands.txt      client_secrets.json  lastupdatecheck.txt  oauth2.txt           oauth2service.json
LICENSE              gam                  nobrowser.txt        oauth2.txt.lock
/app/functions/gam_startup/gam_3 # gam
/bin/sh: gam: not found
/app/functions/gam_startup/gam_3 # bash
bash-5.1# gam
bash: gam: command not found
bash-5.1# ls
GamCommands.txt      client_secrets.json  lastupdatecheck.txt  oauth2.txt           oauth2service.json
LICENSE              gam                  nobrowser.txt        oauth2.txt.lock
bash-5.1# GamCommands.txt
bash: GamCommands.txt: command not found
bash-5.1#
```

[image]

Also here is my Dockerfile if needed:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

LABEL name="testcontainer"
ENV STATIC_URL /app/static
ENV STATIC_PATH "C:\Users\cloudstrife\Documents\scripts\AAOA\AA_W\static"
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN apk add --no-cache libffi-dev 
RUN apk add build-base 
RUN pip install py2pip
RUN apk add python2-dev
RUN pip install cffi
RUN apk add libffi-dev
RUN apk add openssl-dev
RUN apk add --update \
  && pip install --upgrade pip  \
  && pip install -r requirements.txt \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

#  Installing powershell
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    ca-certificates \
    less \
    ncurses-terminfo-base \
    krb5-libs \
    libgcc \
    libintl \
    libssl1.1 \
    libstdc++ \
    tzdata \
    userspace-rcu \
    zlib \
    icu-libs \
    curl
RUN apk -X https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main add --no-cache \
    lttng-ust
RUN curl -L https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.2.2/powershell-7.2.2-linux-alpine-x64.tar.gz -o /tmp/powershell.tar.gz
RUN mkdir -p /opt/microsoft/powershell/7
RUN tar zxf /tmp/powershell.tar.gz -C /opt/microsoft/powershell/7
RUN chmod +x /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh
RUN ln -s /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh /usr/bin/pwsh

# install exchange powershell
RUN pwsh -command "Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement" -Force
RUN pwsh -command "Install-Module -Name PSWSMan" -Force
RUN pwsh -command 'Install-WSMan'

COPY "/" /app

EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5985
EXPOSE 5986
```

**EDIT** - I also tried @LinFelix's idea but no luck(Tried both relative path and full path):
[image]

**EDIT** - I also tried @Josip's idea but no luck either (Specially, trying to use `chmod +x gam`. IT SEES the file but I still can't execute.)
[image]

Comment: try with `./gam` instead of `gam`

Comment: @LinFelix - I just tried and it failed. I also updated my post to show that as well. (Check the bottom). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @LinFelix - I tried both relative path and full path as you suggested but I still got no luck. I also updated the post to show a picture of the new resulting failures. Thanks again for the suggestion though!

Comment: This often means a *library* the executable needs is not found.

Comment: Use `ldd` on your executable to list the libraries it's linked to.

Comment: (Re: edits -- `chmod 755` includes `chmod +x`; if `chmod 755` didn't work, `chmod +x` won't either.)

Comment: ...so _really_, the next step is to run `ldd` to list the library dependencies, and check if they exist in the container.

Comment: I just did and I got a weird error. I am going to post it to the main post now.

Comment: (in particular, alpine ships with musl libc, whereas Linux applications are often compiled against GNU libc; plenty of other things it could be, but that's a particularly common library dependency error using binaries compiled for other distros on Alpine)

Comment: You are completely right. I am and checking this link out now to see if it helps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66974607

Answer (score 0):

After talking with @CharlesDuffy I released my compiled binary that was made in debian wont work in alpine directly. I decided to reinstall gam in the docker container directly, then copy the binary I need so I can use it in multiple different folders.

The details on what you can test to try and get a binary from libc working on alpine is in this stackoverflow link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66974607