# Why I can't run GraalVM native image with Alpine docker image?

Tags: java, graalvm

My goal is to run native image file created by GraalVM with Alpine docker because the Docker Image with GraalVM JDK size is too big, around `587.82 MB`

What I've did:

1. Use GraalVM JDK, and it works when I try to call `./main`

```
FROM ghcr.io/graalvm/native-image:java11-21.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src/main/java/ /app
RUN javac Main.java
RUN native-image Main

FROM ghcr.io/graalvm/jdk:java11-21.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=0 /app/main /app/main
CMD ./main
```

The problem is when I try to switch GraalVM JDK to Alpine

```
FROM ghcr.io/graalvm/native-image:java11-21.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src/main/java/ /app
RUN javac Main.java
RUN native-image Main

FROM alpine:3.15
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=0 /app/main /app/main
CMD ./main
```

It throws an error `native-image_1  | /bin/sh: ./main: not found`

Comment: AFAIK If you compile binary on default Linux, it compiles with dependencies to `stdlibc` or something like that. Whereas `Alpine Linux` has no these libraries, it uses `musl` instead. This may the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Alpine executable binary not found even if in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963068/docker-alpine-executable-binary-not-found-even-if-in-path)

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to add this line:

```
RUN apk add gcompat
```

Thanks @Egor, whose response guided me to find the solution in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70256941/2253308).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `RUN native-image Main` with `RUN native-image --static Main`.

Explanation: Alpine uses a different glibc implementation from the linux used to build the binary. When you use the option `--static` all glibc from the linux you build are going to be included in the binary.

If you need more detail see https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/386