# How to run a downloaded executable on Alpine?

Tags: .net-core, sh, alpine-linux

My script is quite basic and works on Debian:

```
apt update && apt install wget -y
cd /root
wget https://aka.ms/dotnet-counters/linux-x64 -O dotnet-counters
chmod a+x dotnet-counters
./dotnet-counters collect -p 1
```

now, replacing the `apt` for its equivalent `apk`, lines 1 to 4 run without any hiccups but line 5 says `sh: ./dotnet-counters: not found`... if I run a `ls -l` command I see

```
total 14332
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      14675612 Jun  8 23:08 dotnet-counters
```

with `dotnet-counters` in green font (don't know if that means anything)

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1:**
`file dotnet-counters` says `not found`, also here's a screenshot, perhaps im missing something:
[image]

Comment: What does `file dotnet-counters`say?

Comment: it says `not found`... I added a screenshot also, check Edit1

Comment: Looks like it can't find the `file` utility. Maybe Alpine Linux have the absolute minimum of support for basic operations and you need to install a package that contains the `file` utility.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Alpine executable binary not found even if in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963068/docker-alpine-executable-binary-not-found-even-if-in-path)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you are correctly running the executable.

You are not able to run *any* executable on alpine linux, just like on any system. You have to have executable *compatible* with alpine.